# Reading specific column from .csv in C++

Tags: c++, csv

I have a .csv file that has around 5 rows and it looks something like this:

```
"University of Illinois, Chicago","1200, West Harrison","41.3233313","88.221376"
```

The first column is the name of the building, the second is the address and the third and fourth column represent the latitude and longitude. 
I want to take only the values in the 3rd and 4th column for every row.

If I use the getline method and separate every entry with `,` I do not get the desired result. Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
ifstream file("Kiosk Coords.csv");
    double latt[num_of_lines];
    double longg[num_of_lines];
    string name;
    string address;
    string latitude;
    string longitude;
    flag = 0;

    while(file.good()){     
            getline(file,name,',');
            getline(file,address,',');
            getline(file,latitude,',');
            getline(file,longitude,'\n');
            //cout<<name<<" "<<address<<" "<<latitude<<" "<<longitude<<endl;
            cout<<longitude<<endl;
    }
```

For the above given input, I get the following values in the variable if I use my method:

```
name = "University of Illinois"
address = "Chicago
latitude = "1200"
longitude = "West Harrison,41.3233313,88.221376"
```

What I specifically want is this:

```
latitude = "41.3233313"
longitude = "88.221376"
```

Please help

Comment: `"University of Illinois, Chicago"` -- What do you think would happen when this was given to `getline`?  It isn't smart enough to figure out that the embedded comma is not to be considered.  Either write a true csv parser, or get one of the many ones floating around here and on the web.

Comment: I get that. I was wondering if there was some kind of operator that could separate column wise

Comment: There is no "operator".  The only "operator" would be good old fashioned "write a function".

Comment: [You could use something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c).  Your requirements are more than delimiting on the comma -- you have quoted strings that can contain commas, and to properly parse that requires more sophistication.

Comment: I would suggest you change the delimiter of the csv file to a non-conflict one, e.g. '\t'. Never ',' and '.' !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++14's [std::quoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) to the rescue:

```
char comma;
file >> std::quoted(name) >> comma          // name: University of Illinois, Chicago
     >> std::quoted(address) >> comma       // address: 1200, West Harrison
     >> std::quoted(latitude) >> comma      // latitude: 41.3233313
     >> std::quoted(longitude) >> std::ws;  // longitude: 88.221376
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6ac6fe19facc5c4)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to manually parse it. Given that all elements are wrapped in quotes, you can easily extract them by just looking for the quotes.

Read a whole line then look for a pair quotes, and take the content between them.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(file, str);
std::vector<std::string> cols;
std::size_t a, b;

a = str.find('\"', 0);
while (true) {
    b = str.find('\"', a + 1);
    if (b != std::string::npos){
        cols.push_back(str.substr(a, b-a));
    }
    a = str.find('\"', b + 1);
}
```

Results (double quote included):

```
cols[0]: "University of Illinois, Chicago"
cols[1]: "1200, West Harrison"
cols[2]: "41.3233313"
cols[3]: "88.221376"
```